# Solution for onpaste in Opera <= 11.11

Tags: javascript, jquery, onpaste

```
$('#sometextarea')
    .change(function(){console.log($(this).val());})
    [0].onpaste=function(){
        var self=$(this);
        var intr=setInterval(function(){
            if(self.val().length) {
                clearInterval(intr);
                self.blur();                                                                    
            }
        },10);                          
    }
```

`onpaste` doesn't work in Opera.

Can someone suggest better solution for this task?

Because I don't like that I have to use `setInterval`/`setTimeout` and emulate change event.
Because if using `triggerHandler('change')` causes second event triggering on user blur, don't know why actually, it shouldn't by idea, because data isn't changed after first `triggerHandler('change')`

Need a solution to capture `val()` before user exits textarea, mouse paste should be captured as well.

Comment: Yea i guess it's the only workaround. Could you post it as an answer to this topic so i could accept it?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is little late to the party, but I've been working on capturing paste events in the browser. I'm still working on the code but what I have so far is at http://jsfiddle.net/JgU37/42/.

the gist of the code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Fake paste
    var doFakePaste = false;
    $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
        $('#status').html('metaKey: ' + e.metaKey + 
                          ' ctrlKey: ' + e.ctrlKey + 
                          ' which: ' + e.which);

        // These browser work with the real paste event
        if ($.client.browser === "Chrome")
            return;
        if ($.client.os === "Windows" && $.client.browser === "Safari")
            return;

        // Check for patse keydown event
        if (!doFakePaste &&
            ($.client.os === "Mac" && e.which == 86 && e.metaKey) ||
            ($.client.os !== "Mac" && e.which == 86 && e.ctrlKey)) {
            doFakePaste = true;
            // got a paste
            if (!$("*:focus").is("input") &&
                !$("*:focus").is("textarea")) {
                $('#status').html('fake paste');

                // Focus the offscreen editable
                $('#TribblePaste').focus();

                // Opera doesn't support onPaste events so we have
                // to use a timeout to get the paste
                if ($.client.browser === "Opera")
                {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        doFakePaste = false;
                        var html = $('#TribblePaste').html();
                        var text = $('#TribblePaste').text();
                        if (text == '') text = $('#TribblePaste').val();
                        $('#resultA').text('[o] '+html);
                        $('#resultB').text('[o] '+text);
                        $('#TribblePaste').val('');
                        $('#TribblePaste').text('');
                        $('#TribblePaste').blur();
                    }, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }).on('paste', function (e) {
        // Firefox is not supported - they don't
        // expose the real clipboard
        if ($.client.browser === 'Firefox')
            return;

        $('#status').html('paste event');

        // real pasteing
        var html = '';
        var text = '';
        if (window.clipboardData) // IE
        {  
            text = window.clipboardData.getData("Text");
        }
        if (e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.getData) // Standard
        {
            text = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
            text = e.clipboardData.getData('text/html');
        }
        if (e.originalEvent.clipboardData &&
            e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData) // jQuery
        {
            text = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
            html = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/html');
        }
        $('#resultA').text(html);
        $('#resultB').text(text);
    });

    // Setup the offscreen paste capture area
    $('<textarea contenteditable id="TribblePaste"></textarea>').css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': '-100000px',
        'width': '100px',
        'height': '100px'
    }).on('paste', function(e) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            doFakePaste = false;
            var html = $('#TribblePaste').html();
            var text = $('#TribblePaste').text();
            if (text == '') text = $('#TribblePaste').val();
            $('#resultA').text(html);
            $('#resultB').text(text);
            $('#TribblePaste').val('');
            $('#TribblePaste').text('');
            $('#TribblePaste').blur();
        }, 1);
    }).appendTo('body');

    $('#data').html('os: ' + $.client.os + ' browser: ' + $.client.browser);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, it's simply not supported. The only workaround I can think of, is using `setInterval` to detect these kind of changes.